# Jibx Maven plugin: how to set Java package in xsd -> Java transform when namespace was defined

Tags: java, maven, jibx

I use Spring Object-Xml mapping with Jibx to convert some xsd files to Java source files. Jibx is called by jibx-maven-plugin in the build process. My schema files (.xsd) have a namespace "a.b.com" but I want that the generated Java sources are under package "a.com" because the rest of the Java code is organized like that.

I noticed Java packages are determined automatically based on xsd's namespace. Therefore, the question: is it possible to set the java package of output Java source files in xsd->Java transform when using the Jibx Maven plugin when a namespace was defined in the the schema files?

Proposed solutions so far:

1) Use build executions

Proposed below.

Problems:

- xsd->Java transform is run every build. I want to manually run it or that is only run when I change xml schemas.
- prefer-inline attribute in customization.xml acts differently with this setup, inlining attributes of an object reference

2) Use customization xml to set Java package

Proposed here: [Jibx Codegen: customization file - package per schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918691/jibx-codegen-customization-file-package-per-schema)

Problem: It did not work.

3) modular schema

Proposed here: [Jibx Maven plugin: cross-reference among schemas when they are converted in different build executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909972/jibx-maven-plugin-cross-reference-among-schemas-when-they-are-converted-in-diff)

Problem: Too complicated to setup one pom for each schema, generating a jar for each schema and importing the jar in other schemas.

Was anybody successful to solve these issues and was able to set custom Java packages in a xsd->Java conversion when namespace is defined in the xml schemas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [documentation it can be done like the following:](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/schema-codegen.html)

```xml
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLocation>src/main/conf</schemaLocation>
        <includeSchemas>
            <includeSchema>myschema.xsd</includeSchema>
        </includeSchemas>
        <options>
            <package>my.package</package>
        </options>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But you should be carefull about using the packagename instead of the defaults which are coming from the xsd-namespaces, cause it can happen that you will get clashes within the generated source if you have multiple namespaces.

You can define multiple executions to have different schematas having different package names.

```xml
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schemata-a</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <schemaLocation>src/main/conf-a</schemaLocation>
              <includeSchemas>
                <includeSchema>myschema.xsd</includeSchema>
              </includeSchemas>
              <options>
                <package>my.package.a</package>
              </options>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>schemata-b</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <schemaLocation>src/main/conf-b</schemaLocation>
              <includeSchemas>
                <includeSchema>xyz.xsd</includeSchema>
              </includeSchemas>
              <options>
                <package>my.package.b</package>
              </options>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you can change the namespaces in your xsd files makes life easier.

Comment: I'd like to have different packages for each set of schemas, not only one package for all schemas. Is this possible? Otherwise, I'll drop the package tag in the pom.xml and I will need to change the XML namespace in the schema files to reflect the Java package I want in the output Java source files.

Comment: I tried changing the namespace in my xsd, but this namespace is declared in xmls loaded at runtime, I can't change the xmls and Jibx gives me an unmarshalling error at runtime if the xsd namespace doesn't match the xml namespace. Thefore, I gave up of that alternative. I then tried your method (which seems the most correct) of configuring a package for each schema set. I've splitted the jibx plugin config in executions, but it does not work. The plugin never looks for the schemas defined in the <execution> tags. Have you tested this solution? fyi I'm manually running mvn jibx:schema-codegen.

Comment: Correcting my previous comment, the proposed jibx plugin configuration works.  However, it does not run when I run "mvn jibx:schema-codegen" (no xsds are converted), it runs every time I run "mvn package". Is it possible to alter this behavior as it was before (codegen was only run I ran "mvn jibx:schema-codegen")?

Comment: Also, I have a prefer-inline attribute enabled in the Jibx customization xml. Using several build executions, one of my object references in a output Java source code was changed to all attributes of this object. If i disable prefer-inline attribute , it works, but then I lose inner classes. With this issue and the other one mentioned in my last comment, this solution does not satisfy my needs. Any help?

Comment: @khmarbaise..how does this work when I have imports in my xsd file? For example I have a ComplexType XYZ in my current schema and another ComplexType with same name XYZ is present in the imported schema. Now when set the package option the second one overwrites the first one. How do we solve this?