# Jibx Maven plugin: cross-reference among schemas when they are converted in different build executions

Tags: java, maven, jibx

I use the jibx Maven plugin to convert some xsds to Java source codes. In a schema A, there is a reference to a type defined in a schema B. Before, I used this pom.xml configuration and everything worked fine:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLocation>${basedir}/resources/oxm/schemas</schemaLocation>
        <schemaBindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/java</schemaBindingDirectory>
        <includeSchemas>
            <includeSchema>schemaA.xsd</includeSchema>
            <includeSchema>schemaB.xsd</includeSchema>
            <includeSchema>schemaC.xsd</includeSchema>
        </includeSchemas>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The input schema A is something like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="myApp.com/schema/schemaA"targetNamespace="http://myApp.com/schema/schemaA" xmlns:rsType="http://myApp.com/schema/schemaB">
<xs:import schemaLocation="schemaB.xsd" namespace="http://myApp.com/schema/schemaB" />
<xs:complexType name="classAType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="objB" type="rsType:classBType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="foo" type="xs:int" />
 </xs:complexType>
```

Input schema B has similar code with definition of classBType.

The former Java source output was something like:

```
class classA
{
    classB objB;
    int foo;
}
```

Recently, I separated the conversion of schemas in different build executions in the pom.xml to be able to define different target package for them. My new pom.xml is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLocation>${basedir}/resources/oxm/schemas</schemaLocation>
        <schemaBindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/java</schemaBindingDirectory>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>schemaCodegenA</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <includeSchemas>
                     <includeSchema>schemaA.xsd</includeSchema>
                  </includeSchemas>
                  <options>
                      <package>com.myApp.jibxgenerated.schema.resource</package>
                  </options>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
```

(... one execution for each set of schemas)

The Java source output now is:

```
class classA
{
    // all properties of class B here
    int classBattrib1;
    int classBattrib2;
    int classBattribN;
    int foo;
}
```

Is this the expected behavior? I want to have the classB reference back in the class A source code, is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I discovered this issue is generated by a prefer-inline attrib in a customization xml given to Jibx using the jibx-maven plugin. I used this attrib to create inner classes whenever possible, but apparently it also inlines attributes sometimes. I don't know the heuristics used to inline code, as it does not happen in a simple test case that I created, very similar to the schemas mentioned here (2 schemas, in which one imports the other and the former uses the latter to define a complex type). Also, the issue does not happen when all schemas are handled in just one execution, as mentioned b4.

Answer (score 1):

user1550682,

Actually JiBX handles this case pretty easily. You can package each schema in a separate jar and easily reference a sub-module using the maven plugin.

Take a look at the instructions for modular schema here:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/modular-codegen.html

and take a look at the example code in github here:
https://github.com/jibx/maven-plugin/tree/master/test-suite/base-binding-test

This example uses three simple schema: company -> address -> person. and had a simple test that marshalls and unmarshalls some xml.

I hope this helps!

Don

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to require a lot of extra work (creating one jar and one pom for each schema). I just want that Maven jibx plugin NOT create Java packages based on schema namespace, it should let me customize the destination package for each schema. Including/importing one xml schema inside another worked fine before, it broke when I split source generation in several build executions (only way I found to use my custom Java packages). Also, prefer-inline attrib is enabled in customization.xml; if I turn it off, the issue is solved, but then I lose inner classes.