# Jibx Codegen: customization file - package per schema

Tags: java, maven, jibx

I'm using Jibx maven plugin in a project to generate Java source from XML schema (xsd) files. I've configured the plugin in the pom.xml to use a customization xml. In this xml, I define a Java package per schema, as presented here:

```
<schema-set>
    <schema name="schema1.xsd" package="com.myApp.jibxgenerated.schema.schema1"/>
    <schema name="schema2.xsd" package="com.myApp.jibxgenerated.schema.schema2" includes="element1" />
    <schema name="schema3.xsd" package="com.myApp.jibxgenerated.schema.schema3" includes="element1 element2" />
</schema-set>
```

I have namespaces defined in these schemas. The output Java source files still use the namespace defined in the schemas to create a Java package, ignoring my package attribute in the customization.xml.

I know the customization.xml is being read and used in the source code generation because there are some other customizations that work correctly.

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

At http://jibx.sourceforge.net/fromschema/codegen-customs.html they nest multiple `schema-set`s within an outer `schema-set`.  Try this:

```
<schema-set>
  <schema-set package="com.myApp.jibxgenerated.schema.schema1">
    <schema name="schema1.xsd"/>
  </schema-set>
  <schema-set package="com.myApp.jibxgenerated.schema.schema2">
    <schema name="schema2.xsd" includes="element1" />
  </schema-set>
  <schema-set package="com.myApp.jibxgenerated.schema.schema3">
    <schema name="schema3.xsd" includes="element1 element2" />
  </schema-set>
</schema-set>
```

Comment: According to documentation (http://jibx.sourceforge.net/fromschema/codegen-customs.html), the package attrib should work in the schema AND schema-set tags. Nevertheless, I tried your suggestion, adding a names attribute in the children schema-set to restrict the schema-set to contain the desired schemas. It did not work, strangely only 1 schema was generated in the desired package, the others were generated in packages derived from schemas namespaces. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using jibx rather than JAXB?

Comment: I didn't choose the jibx framework earlier and I won't choose another xml framework now only to have this feature.

Comment: What do you mean you "didn't choose the jibx framework earlier"?  JAXB is built into the Java6 SDK and you'll find it a lot easier to get support...